# Visual Basic send password to sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, vba

I have a sharepoint site that will be used by many users but I don't know who these users are in advance. This site hosts an xls file that a macro needs to run on. I am able to open the file with the following:

```
    Sub macro1()
    xlFile = "The URL"
    File: 'TheWorkbook.xls"
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlFile, , False)
    End Sub
```

However I need to be able to send a username and password tot he sharepoint site. Since I don't know who my users are in advance I am using an application ID that has a password associated with it. Any ideas? I've tried sendkeys but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you must secure the workbook, then use a windows security group and ensure all users who need access are in that group. This would allow integrated authentication to take care of it for you.

If you say you have no way to know what group they should be in, then you should question why you are securing the workbook in the first place.

Comment: It isn't necessarily a shared workbook it is used more like a data source. I can't know the users in advance because of high turnover and I don't want an admin to have to come in and add a user every single time there is a new one.